# CITextField in admin is displayed as text area, not as one line

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin

I'm using python 3.9 with django 4.1

I'm just starting to play with it, I want to use CITextField from Postgresql
so i imported it from `django.contrib.postgres.fields`, it works fine but that admin displays it as TextArea, which means it's not a one-liner input text, it's a all box of text to enter even if i configured a max length of 100 characters. how can I correct that?

as an example to show the problem I created a Country model with `name_en` which is a `CharField` and `name_fr` and `name_he` which are `CITextField`, all of them are set to max length of 100 characters:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"
    name_en = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name="English Country Name", max_length=100)
    name_fr = CITextField(unique=True, verbose_name="French Country Name", max_length=100)
    name_he = CITextField(unique=True, verbose_name="Hebrew Country Name", max_length=100)
```

when i browse it on the admin page this is the result:

[image: admin page of country model]

what can I do to resolve it ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can create my own model class and use it to return a `TextInput` instead of `FormField`, I don't really like that answer, I notice that CharField width is longer than my custom textField so it doesn't act exactly the same.

So this is `MyCITextField` that I defined:

```
class MyCITextField(CITextField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({"widget": forms.TextInput})
        return super(MyCITextField, self).formfield(**kwargs)
```

And while having this as my model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"
    name_en = MyCITextField(unique=True, verbose_name="English Country Name", max_length=100)
    name_fr = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name="French Country Name", max_length=100)
    name_he = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name="Hebrew Country Name", max_length=100)
```

the result is:

[image: MyCITextField used]

so as you can see that don't share the same with, i want the visuality to be the same.